# How do i modify this to implement an adjacency list of a undirected, weighted graph?

Tags: java, graph, nodes, adjacency-list, edges

```
import java.util.*;

class Graph{
    private int numVertices;
    class AdjacentNode{
        public int parentNodeIndex;
        public AdjacentNode next;
        public AdjacentNode(int parentNum, AdjacentNode neighbor){
            this.parentNodeIndex=parentNum;
            next = neighbor;
        }
    }
    class Vertex{
        String name;
        AdjacentNode neighborList;
        public Vertex (String name){
            this.name = name;
        }
        public String toString(){
            return "(" + name+ ")";
        }
    }
    Vertex [] adjLists;
    public Graph (int n){
        adjLists = new Vertex[n];
        numVertices=0;
    }
    public int getNumVertices(){
        return numVertices;
    }
    public void setNumVertices(int v){
        numVertices = v;
    }
    public void add_vertex(String label){
        int num = getNumVertices();
        setNumVertices(num+1);

        adjLists[num]= new Vertex(label);   
    }
    public void add_edge (String startNode, String endNode)
    {
        int v1 = indexForName(startNode);
        int v2 = indexForName(endNode); 
            adjLists[v1].neighborList = new AdjacentNode(v2, 
adjLists[v1].neighborList);
    }
    int indexForName(String n){
        for (int i=0; i< adjLists.length; i++){
            if(adjLists[i].name.equals(n)){
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getAdjacentNodes(String parentNode){
        int v1 = indexForName(parentNode);
        ArrayList<String> a= new ArrayList<String>();
        System.out.println("The adjacent nodes of " + parentNode + " =>");
        for (AdjacentNode neighbor=adjLists[v1].neighborList; neighbor!=null; 
                neighbor = neighbor.next){
        a.add(0, adjLists[neighbor.parentNodeIndex].name);
        Collections.sort(a);
        }   
        return a;   
    }
    public void print (){
        System.out.println();
        for(int i =0; i<adjLists.length; i++){
            System.out.print(adjLists[i].name);
            for (AdjacentNode neighbor=adjLists[i].neighborList; neighbor!=null; 
                    neighbor = neighbor.next){
                System.out.print("-->" + adjLists[neighbor.parentNodeIndex].name);
            }
            System.out.println("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

This is my Graph class and Vertex class to implement an adjacency list of a directed unweighted graph. How do i modify this to implement an adjacency list of a undirected, weighted graph? I want to add a method to my graph class that is

`public int getGraphsTotalWeight()` in order to get the sum of the weights of all edges in the graph.

My graph class is suppose to have the following methods implemented, which I tried to add onto my code above.

/* Add a new node to the graph. The newly added node will have no edges */

```
public void add_vertex(String label)
```

/* Add an edge to the graph connecting node ‘startNode’ to node ‘endNode’. If such edge already exist in the graph, your code should ignore adding. Your code should run in O(|E|) in the worst case. */

```
public void add_edge(String startNode, String endNode)
```

/** Returns a list of names of all adjacent Nodes to node parentNode. List should be in alphabetical order. */

```
public ArrayList<String>  getAdjacentNodes(String parentNode)
```

/** Returns a weight of the graph (i.e. the sum of the weights of all edges in the graph. */

```
public int getGraphsTotalWeight()
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The most trivial way to turn a directed graph into an undirected graph is to add a reverse-direction edge to every existing edge. Then every algorithm for a directed graph should work, as long as it works with cyclic graphs.

Comment: is that the only way?